# How can I setup hostnames for applications on my local network?

Tags: networking, dns

I've been gradually over the years writing programs for personal use. It's my day job too, these are just side projects I use myself. Anyway, at first it was no big deal, but now that I'm up to 6 of them I'm trying to tame the beast, as it were. Lots of changes to better organize my overall ecosystem and make the deployments of each app easier to manage.

One of the things I would like to do is assign them human-readable names. For example, one of them is http://localhost:7001 on my desktop, but http://192.168.5.27:7001 from my other devices around the house. I would prefer to be able to navigate to http://my-app-name, and it automatically route there.

I know this is getting into the realm of DNS, which is not an area I'm super experienced in. What level of effort is required to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can start by configuring your local machine.  For example, if you have a Windows laptop, navigate to `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` and edit that file.  It has entries there for mapping IPv4 and IPv6 address to domain names.

The more you scale up your operation, the less feasible that approach is.  To go a step further, you need a DNS server.  For example, on a Windows network, you can [configure a server](https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/11019-set-up-configure-dns-on-windows-server-2016.html) as a dedicated domain controller and/or DNS server.  DNS records are created and managed on that server.  Then, to leverage that DNS server from your laptop, you can configure your network card by specifying the DNS servers (primary and secondary) to use by specifying their IP addresses.

**To setup a DNS server (Linux)** - Assume two servers, private IPv4 addresses:

- ns1 - 192.168.10.11 - primary DNS server
- host1 - 192.168.100.101 - your Linux laptop on the LAN

@ns1

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install bind9 bind9utils bind9-doc`
3. `OPTIONS="-4 -u bind"` (`/etc/default/bind9`)
4. add trusted acl list (`/etc/bind/named.conf.options`)
5. set config options (`/etc/bind/named.conf.options`)
6. set forward zone (`/etc/bind/named.conf.local`)
7. set reverse zone (`/etc/bind/named.conf.local`)
8. create forward zone file (`/etc/bind/zones/db.foo.my_zone.com`)
9. create reverse zone file (`/etc/bind/zones/db.168.192`)
10. `sudo named-checkconf`
11. `sudo named-checkzone foo.my_zone.com db.foo.my_zone.com`
12. `sudo named-checkzone 168.192.in-addr.arpa /etc/bind/zones/db.192.168`
13. `sudo service bind9 restart`

@host1

14. add name servers (`/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`)
15. `sudo resolvconf -u`

Comment: Can you provide non-windows instructions for setting up a DNS server? Maybe something I can tie to my entire local network? I run all linux machines.